# TypeError: unbound method navigate_to_page() must be called with className instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

This is my `Python` Code:

```
class SearchTest(BaseTestCase,unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SearchTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.navigate_to_page(keyword_Constants['URL'])

    def test1_Search(self):
        homepageObj= HomePage(self.driver)
        homepageObj._verifypage()
        searchObj = SearchPage(self.driver)
        searchField = searchObj.searchKeyword("chicken")

    def test2_CountSearchResultVal(self):
        searchObj = SearchPage(self.driver)
        #searchField = searchObj.countSearchResultVal("chicken")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(SearchTest, cls).tearDownClass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

When I try to use this class method, following error pops up:

```
TypeError: unbound method navigate_to_page() must be called with SearchTest instance as first argument (got str instance instead).
```

Comment: I don't know Python very well, but I think `cls.navigate_to_page(self, keyword_Constants['URL'])` should work.

Comment: Not familiar with the class tree that defines `navigate_to_page`, but it seems not to be a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) (it can't be called on a class, only on instance), therefore you can't call it from a _classmethod_ (in your case you should move it to `setUp`).